# converting timestamps in hive to date

Tags: hive

I have this format of data in a hive column.

```
09/05/2015  12:45:00
```

I am trying to convert it to this format

```
20150905, or with semicolons - 2015-09-05
```

What is the most efficient way and without going through linux timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `date_format`.
If your data is in String/Timestamp/Date format,
and you want a string of format `yyyy-MM-dd`, then use-
`date_format(date_time_col, 'yyyy-MM-dd')`
and you want a date format , then use-
`cast( date_format(date_time_col, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as date)`

***EDIT***
In case you have a string 'MM/dd/yyyy', you need to split the string and concat them before senting them to date_format.

```
date_format( 
concat_ws('-', substr(split(date_time_col,'/')[2],1,4),split(date_time_col,'/')[0], split(date_time_col,'/')[1] )
, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

And you can combine all like this -

```
case when date_format(date_time_col, 'yyyy-MM-dd') is null 
date_format( 
concat_ws('-', substr(split(date_time_col,'/')[2],1,4),split(date_time_col,'/')[0], split(date_time_col,'/')[1] )
, 'yyyy-MM-dd') 
else date_format(date_time_col, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
end
```

Comment: Thanks. What am I missing here? 
select (cast(date_format(a.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as date) as event_dt, count (*) 
from  amit_chicago_orc a

Comment: And, this casts results in a null

Comment: if the cast result is null then, pls check `date_format(date_time_col, 'yyyy-MM-dd')` output as well. it may be null as well. cast will convert above formatted string to date.

Comment: They are null, as the to_date ones. I think the culprit is that some data contains this format '07/09/2002 07:30:00 PM'. Is there a way around here?

Comment: date format can only handle 'yyyy-MM-dd' formatted string. So, you may need to create the string first to use it in the formula. i edited the answer